# Add typing using keyof for nested keys at the same level

Tags: typescript, keyof

Working on a game with a group, and it had a little encyclopedia. I was able to get some of it from JS to TS, which I'm slowly learning. But the structure has changed. Say the structure looks like the following:

```
const enycData = [
  {
  "Items": {
    "Apple": {...},
    ...
  },
  "Locations": {
    "Apple Land": {...},
    ...
  },
  ...
]
```

In practice, we will only ever be calling "Apple" or "Apple Land" in our functions based on the way everything else goes, and I'd like to be able to catch typos: `openEncyc("Apple")`. I expect each of these properties will be unique.

I don't need to do any arbitrary crawling, it will always be that deep. An array of objects representing categories, and then each article title in a category.

I had seen some guides using things like `T extends T ? keyof T: never` but I couldn't quite get it to click.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mapped type like so:

```
type K = {[i in Exclude<keyof typeof enycData, keyof []>]: 
           {[k in keyof typeof enycData[i]]: 
              keyof typeof enycData[i][k]}[keyof typeof enycData[i]]}[
              Exclude<keyof typeof enycData, keyof []>];
// "Apple" | "Apple Land"
```

This can be simplified with a helper type to get a union of the value types of an object.

```
type Values<T> = T[keyof T];
type K = Values<{[i in Exclude<keyof typeof enycData, keyof []>]: Values<{[k in keyof typeof enycData[i]]: keyof typeof enycData[i][k]}>}>;
```

Comment: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmAnsAIgQymmBeGBtAKBhgG8iYAiASSjgFsIKAuU84igQQAcuAbOZqQC+AGnKjyFADIhgGAJbhGLMsXbc+cGFLRgAJoJITiQ8QQC6AbgJREXLQBUcpPAGsY8sDFdxEIAGYwtvYB8EioGGh4YACudABGcABO5uYwLD5+gcFwoQjI6JjRcYkpbuZCbr6hOXnhhVGxCcmp1gD0bWoAegD8BEA)

Comment: This is really close! The playground works and your code works in webstorm. However, if I add a second item to the array, Webstorm finds the initial type as `never`, although it works correctly in playground: 
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmAnsAIgQymmBeGBtAKBhgG8iYAiASSjgFsIKAuU84igQQAcuAbOZqQC+AGnKjyFADIhgGAJbhGLMsXbc+cGFLRgAJoJITiQ8WOKrKNestZrKAeQBOugOYCVxmF+myFSwzZHFzB3bV0DT3NvMwIAXQBuAihELi0AFRxSPABrGHkwGBy4RBAAMxgUtPL4JFQMNDwwAFc6ACM4Jzi4mBZi0oqquBqEZHRMJtaOrty4oVySmqGRuvHGlvbO7qSAeh21AD0AfgIgA

Comment: Perhaps this is a better example, it breaks even in playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmAnsAIgQymmBeGBtAKBhgG8iYAiASSjgFsIKAuU84igQQAcuAbOZqQC+AGnKjyFADIhgGAJbhGLMsXbc+cGFLRgAJoJITiQ8WOKrKAdThouSw20oBlAO4gATnuXDzMUyZiALoA3ARQiFxaACo4pHgA1jDyYDAJcIggAGYwEVHZ8EioGGh4YACudABGcB5BQTAs6Zk5eXAFCMjomGWVNXWJQUKJGQVtHUXdpRXVtfVhAPQLagB6APwEQA

Comment: @lowercase_donkey I've updated my answer. [New playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApmAnsAIgQymmBeGBtAKBhgG8iYAiASSjgFsIKAuU84igQQAcuAbOZqQC+AGnKjyFADIhgGAJbhGLMsXbc+cGFLRgAJoJITiQ8WOKrKAdThouSw20oBlAO4gATnuXDzMUyZiALowaBAwoJBQANwEUIhcWgDSOKR48jDyYDAAogAewLwArnpwADwA1nCIIABmMPGJdfBIqBhoIjBVNfV4QQB8QSp4FZnZ3c2NcM0IyOiY6UFDXdWTCdP1s20L8kEjQUIjq-VTM63zaIsHePmFJeUTJ+tnc+2dj-gDQbEA9D9qAD0APwEIA). Remember to add `as const` to your array declaration.

Comment: This did it!!!!!! You mad lad, thank you soooo much!

Answer (score 0):

The `T extends T ? keyof T : never` pattern can be used with the right `T`, which can, for example, be obtained with `infer`

```
type Keys = typeof encycData extends Record<string, infer T>[] ?
    T extends T ? keyof T : never
  : never;
```